# Angular 2 Decorator properties

Tags: angular, decorator

Can someone give me a link to the properties of an Angular 2 decorator? I keep running into the Angular 1 decorator properties, but it doesn't have Directive. So I really need all the properties available for Angular2. Thank you.

Comment: [RTM](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation for Angular 2's built in decorators is located at https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/#!?type=decorator

angular.io is the official website.

Comment: This does not have directive which is used for nested components, so it makes me think that it is old info.